# Using C# regex, getting a value between two strings

Tags: c#, regex

My test data

```
Date:Fri 14-Mar-2003 Venue:S.F.S. Crowd:24,172
```

The data I am interested in

```
Fri 14-Mar-2003
```

The code I currently have

```
string datePattern = "Date:(.*?) Venue";
string tempDate = Regex.Match(values[(int)HomeColumnNames.VenueCrowdDate], datePattern).Value;
```

The data that is being returned

```
Date:Fri 14-Mar-2003 Venue
```

Any advice or assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes it seemed like my google skills failed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is ok. Just you need to get group one.

```
var match= Regex.Match(values[(int)HomeColumnNames.VenueCrowdDate], datePattern);

match.Groups[0]; //returns full match
match.Groups[1]; //returns 1st group

//Gets MatchCollection
var matches= Regex.Matches(values[ManyAddresses, datePattern);
```

using @bash.d's pattern is better for other samples.

Answer (score 1):

You are including the words into your regex, so they will be in the extracted string. Try

```
string datePattern = @"{\w+}\s+{\d{1,2}-{\w+}-{\d{4,}";
```

Comment: I offered yours but I think the `@`(literal) character should be before `"`  and it didn't match. Are you sure it works ?

Comment: No, you are right! It was in the haste of the moment... Thank you for clarification

Answer (score 1):

You can also loop thought the matched groups.

```
var groups = Regex.Match(values[(int)HomeColumnNames.VenueCrowdDate], datePattern).Groups;
Console.WriteLine(groups[1].Value); //Fri 14-Mar-2003
```

Comment: For java groups start from index 1 but for c# I think it is 0.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz I'm never sure either. it's this uncertainty that is why I suggested explicit group naming :-)

Comment: the array index starts from 0, I'm sure and have also tested the code

Comment: index starts from 0 but 0 index gives us the matched text not group. So group 1 is right for both java and c#. +1

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the match, not your capture group.

The following code will allow you to explicitly name (and subsequently reference) your capture. It's not necessary to explicitly name or number your groups... But it's good practice.

```
String groupName = "yourGroupName";
Regex r = new Regex(@"Date:(?<" + groupName + ">.*?) Venue");
Matches m = r.Match(yourTestData);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[groupName]);
```